# Which answer is right?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

So I had a lesson today and the teacher gave us a question, A: What is wrong? B: I ___________ a glass (break).
My question is, which answer should I give her?

1. I have broken a glass
2. I broke a glass.
3. both could be right.

Comment: Hi ,welcome to ELL! This is not the right place to get your homework done, so please make some research and if you have got some doubt about something edit your question and you will surely find someone ready to help you

Answer (score 1):

Answer is :

3. Both could be right